# Passing vectors into function by reference vs by value in C++

Tags: c++, vector, reference

I have been writing a small project just to expand on my knowledge of c++ and I ran into an issue. When I was accepting a username I wanted to check if it was already taken. If that specific username was taken I re-printed the question to the user. It works fine the first loop, but after that it will accept anything even if it does exist inside the users Vector.

```
     bool verify(char * a, vector<User> b){
 14         for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++){
 15                 if(strcmp(a, b[i].getUsername()) == 0){
 16                         return false;
 17                 }
 18         }
 19         return true;
 20 }
 21 
 22 int main(){
 23 
 24         vector<User> users;
 25 
 26         User us1((char *)"foo", (char *)"bar");
 27         users.push_back(us1);
 28 
 29         
 30         do{
 31                 cout << "Enter Username: ";
 32                 scanf(" %s", username);
 33                 
 34                 
 35         } while(!verify(username, users));
 36         
 37         return 0;
 38 }
```

However, if my function verify instead takes in a vector & b it works fine. Can someone explain why this is happening?

User.cpp

```
    User:: User(char * userName, char * passWord){
  9 
 10         this->userName = strdup(userName);
 11         this->passWord = strdup(passWord);
 12 
 13 }
 14 
 15 User:: ~User(){
 16 
 17         delete userName;
 18         delete passWord;
 19 
 20 }
 21 
 22 void User::getMessage(){
 23 
 24         cout << message << endl;
 25 }
 26 
 27 char * User:: getUsername(){
 28 
 29         return userName;
 30 }
 31 
 32 char * User :: getPassword(){
 33 
 34         return passWord;
 35 }
 36 
 37 void User:: printUser(){
 38 
 39         cout << "User Information" << endl;
 40         cout << "Username: "<< userName << endl;
 41         cout << "Password: "<< passWord << endl;
 42         cout << "Messages: "<< ((message == NULL) ? "User has no messages\n" : "User has 1 message\n");
 43 
 44 }
```

Comment: If you're using `strcmp` in C++ you're doing it wrong. `std::string` is your friend here.

Comment: My guess would be `User` contains `char *` and you're violating the rule of three. But since you haven't posted the code for `User` your question is currently unanswerable. Post a [MCVE].

Comment: You use `cout`, use `cin` as well. The variable `username` is not declared here.

Comment: Most likely the copy constructor of `User` is wrong in some way. Otherwise your code should work either way although passing containers by value tends to be a performance problem. However, you don't show the copy constructor of your `User` class.

Comment: 1. Show a [mcve], instead of random small parts of code, if something is not working, not showing most of the non-working code is illogical, see the [mcve] help article for more information. 2. Write real C++ code, instead of C code that pretends that it's C++. strcmp(), scanf(), et al, has no business appearing in real C++ code.

Comment: Note that using `scanf()` as shown is creating a potential for buffer overrun. It also doesn't check whether input was actually successful. A proper use of `scanf()` would be something like `if (1 == scanf("%100s", username) { ... }` where `100` is the number of characters available at the address pointed to by `username`. Things tend to be easier when reading a `std::string` with `std::cin`.

Comment: Ok this may be a dumb question, but why does my user class need a copy constructor?

Comment: The casting of the string literals to `char *` seems somewhat fishy as well.

Comment: @clayton because it's likely that you're wrongly handling pointers and copying, like others already said, we can't help you if you don't show all of the relevant code.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl the casting needs to be done since c++ sees a string as a const char * instead of just a char *. Or at least this is what I have seen in the past if you have any insight on this I would love to hear it!

Comment: @clayton What's with this `strdup` stuff?  You don't need any of this if you're writing C++ code.  In addition, you can't call `delete` on something created with `malloc`.  You should stay away from writing `C` and write C++ code.  Also, your `User` class as you've coded it requires a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator.  The reason is that you're placing these objects in a vector, and vector makes copies.  Your `User` class cannot be copied safely.  Yet again, if you stuck with using `std::string` instead of the `char *` C-isms, this would not be an issue.

Comment: I agree with what everyone else is saying regarding this not using C++ to its full potential. That said, I recommend you read this. I think it will explain why your missing copy constructor is causing problems. http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/912-shallow-vs-deep-copying/

Comment: When you pass the vector by value, each element of the vector is copied. Since you don't define a copy constructor, a simple duplication happens - those copies point to the same const char*s as the originals. So when the vector goes out of scope at the end of the function call, they are deleted and free the memory which both the copies and the originals point to. When you pass by reference there's no copying.

Comment: @kfsone thank you for the explanation! I am new to C++ and as you can tell I am transitioning from vanilla C.

Answer (score 2):

All discussion of using `std::string` aside, the base problem in OP's code is the lack of a user defined copy constructor for the `User` class.  The default one will just copy the values in the `userName` and `passWord` fields, causing both vectors (the one in `main` and the one created for the `verify` function) to point to the same allocated memory address.  When `verify` returns, that memory is delete, leaving the `Users` in the vector in `main` with dangling pointers (pointing to freed memory).

Using the reference instead avoids this deletion and keeps the original vector intact.

Which is one reason why you shouldn't use raw pointers in code these days.

Comment: Thank you! This helps. I am new to this and clearly haven't done full experimentation with things like using strings instead of character arrays

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend using C++ functionality over C stuff wherever possible, it's usually more readable and less error prone.

Now there are multiple problems in your code and [@AlanStrokes' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37504075/passing-vectors-into-function-by-reference-vs-by-value-in-c?noredirect=1#comment62503309_37504075) was right, you're main problem is not correctly dealing with the rule of three.

Your `User` class does dynamical allocation but doesn't define a copyconstructor and assignment operator. For a simple snippet showing the problem, have a look at the snippet [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34715d11adc11f0f). It only copies the addresses, not the actual data that's pointed to, so once the first copy gets deleted all others are invalid.

You also have other problems, `strdup` is non-portable, it's not part of the C standard. It's part of the POSIX standard so most likely only available on systems implementing that standard. Also it's a C function that allocates memory with `malloc`, you should delete the pointer it returns the `free` from C, not the `delete` from C++.

Also there is a reason that string literals are `const char[]` in C++, in fact in C they are `char[]` but you aren't allowed to edit them so it's practically const as well. That's because the compiler is allowed to put string literals into the read only location of the executable. So instead of casting string literals to `char *` make your function correctly take a `const char *`.

---

All that said dealing with those pointer things is annoying since C++ makes it way easier with `std::string` and I'd recommend using that instead:

```
class User {
  private:
    std::string userName;
    std::string password;

    User(const std::string &userName, const std::string & passWord);
    std::string getUsername();
    std::string getPassword();
    void printUser();
};

User::User(const std::string & userName, const std::string & passWord) {
  this->userName = userName;
  this->passWord = passWord;
}

std::string User::getUsername() {
  return userName;
}

std::string User::getPassword() {
  return passWord;
}

// etc...
```

Here C++ automatically handles all the copying and deleting logic and you don't have to deal with annoying pointer stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to work fine, after I make the minimal changes so it actually compiles.
I just used std::string to store a string instead of guessing at your User class.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

struct User {
    std::string name, game;
    User(const char* nam, const char* gam) : name(nam), game(gam) {}
    const char* getUsername() const {
        return name.c_str();
    }
};

bool verify(char * a, std::vector<User> b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
        if (std::strcmp(a, b[i].getUsername()) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main(){    
    std::vector<User> users;

    User us1("foo", "bar");
    users.push_back(us1);

    char username[100];

    do {
        std::cout << "Enter Username: ";
        std::scanf(" %50s", username);
    } while(!verify(username, users));

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this [on ideone](http://ideone.com/Hpu7Dk), inputting "foo" three times and then "Greg", it keeps prompting after each "foo" and then accepts "Greg".

Since substituting another class for your unseen "User" class makes it work, the problem must be in that class, probably in your handling of the pointers that are passed to its constructor.

Some notes:

- There should be no need to cast string literals "foo" and "bar" to `(char*)`; they are already `char*`. If you are doing this to get rid of `const`-ness, don't: they probably reside in read-only memory.
- If you have C++11, the loop in `verify` can be replaced by a range-for:

  ```
  for (auto u : b) {
      if (strcmp(a, u.getUsername()) == 0)
          return false;
  }
  ```
- In fact, you can eliminate the whole function `verify` and use `std::any_of(users.begin(), users.end(), [username](const User& u){ return strcmp(u.getUsername(), username) == 0; })`, which returns `true` if `username` is already in the vector `users`.

So a shorter, equivalent complete program is

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

struct User {
    std::string name, game;
    User(const char* nam, const char* gam) : name(nam), game(gam) {}
    const std::string& getUsername() const {
        return name;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<User> users;
    users.push_back({"foo","bar"});
    std::string username;

    do {
        std::cout << "Enter Username: ";
        std::cin >> username;
    } while(std::any_of(users.begin(), users.end(),
            [username](const auto& u){ return u.getUsername() == username; }));

    return 0;
}
```

([on ideone](http://ideone.com/9vXJYH))